# How to search in table of multiple parameters in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

so there is a table of parameters which is associated with the "offer". The parameters table looks like this:

- offer_id
- parameter_name
- parameter_value

Table entries look like this:

> offer_id | parameter_name | parameter_value
>
> 1 | price | 100
>
> 1 | width | 150
>
> 1 | height | 200
>
> 1 | place | left
>
> 1 | place | right
>
> 2 | price | 300
>
> 2 | width | 150
>
> 2 | height | 200

Now I want to perform a search using MySQL query in this table, where

- **price** is *more* than 80 AND *less* than 120
- **width** is *equal* to 150
- **height** is *equal* to 200
- **place** is *either* left *OR* right

The expected outcome:

- **offer_id = 1**

How would a MySQL query look like?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM offers a
INNER JOIN offers b ON a.offerid = b.offerid
INNER JOIN offers c ON b.offerid = c.offerid
INNER JOIN offers d ON c.offerid = d.offerid
WHERE a.parameter_name = 'price'
AND b.parameter_name = 'width'
AND c.parameter_name = 'height'
AND d.parameter_name = 'place'
AND a.parameter_value BETWEEN 80 AND 120
AND b.parameter_value = '150'
AND c.parameter_value = '200'
AND d.parameter_value IN ('left','right')
```

Note that this will bring back multiple rows sometimes (ie id of 1 would come back more than once). You can remove this with a DISTINCT if you want. Depends how the data is to be used.

Comment: Looks great, but how would I use the DISTINCT if I want just one result of offer_id (ie id of 1 only once).

Comment: Just use SELECT DISTINCT offerid instead of SELECT *

Reason you would get 2 otherwise is for situations such as have a place of left and a place of right for the same offerid. DISTINCT can be used to return unique rows, but if you bring back columns (such as for the place) which are not unique for an offerid then the row would not be unique so DISTINCT would not have any duplicates to eliminate.

You could also use aggregate functions (such as COUNT, MIN, MAX, etc) with a GROUP BY to bring back a meaningful value for each offerid.